# Inserting full bleed images in browser background instead of maps using CartoDB?

Tags: carto, jquery

I am building a product that will utilize high fidelity photography.

I would like to show my photos in a slideshow format that takes up the entire area of the browser.

CartoDB and the Odysssey.js would work well.

Can I substitute the maps for photography in the background of my browser?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can ! :)

In your visualization, click on **Select basemap**

There, in *Custom selection*, click on **IMG**. (capture attached).

[image]

You can upload images up to 1024x1024.